# $L^1$ function unbounded on every interval

Tags: real-analysis

[My question concerns part of Exercise 2.25 in Folland's Real Analysis text.]

I'm looking at the function $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}f(x-r_n)$, where $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere, and $\{r_n\}$ is some enumeration of the rational numbers.  I am trying to prove that $g$ is discontinuous at every point.  It is easy enough to see that $g$ is discontinuous wherever it is finite (since it is unbounded on every interval), and that it is finite almost everywhere (since it is in particular in $L^1$).  However, it seems to me that to show that $g$ is discontinuous at a point $x_0$ with $g(x_0)=+\infty$, one would have to exhibit a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x_0$ such that $\{g(x_n)\}$ is bounded.  It seems intuitively obvious to me that such a sequence exists, but I have not been able to construct one.  Any suggestions? (Hints preferred to answers.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if a function is continuous at a point, it is bounded in some neighborhood of that point.

Comment: Hmm... even for extended real-valued functions? As I understand, such a function (for the sake of definiteness, the function $g$ above) may be continuous even at a point $x_0$ where it attains the value $\infty$, provided that $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)=\infty$. Or am I misinformed?

Comment: I don't have the book, so I'm not sure what the "$\infty$" point means there. You can notice that the left and right limits at a rational point (if they exist) are $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, and that can't be the same thing. May be, consider $g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}|x-r_n|^{-1/2}$?

Comment: Ah--you've brought to my attention a careless mistake I originally made when  defining the function. It has now been corrected-- my apologies.  Given the corrected definition of the function $g$, is it possible to show that, given a point $x_0$ where $g(x_0)=+\infty$, there is a point $y$ arbitrarily close to $x_0$ such that $g(y)\le M$ for some fixed $M$?